# System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles on MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I wanted to convert a small test application from Windows .NET 4 to MonoTouch but I am missing `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles`. 
Then I tried it with a plain Mono console app and the namespace isn't there either. 
I tried Mono 2.10 in combination with MonoDevelop 2.4.

Is it supposed to be there or not? I'm kind of confused, as .NET4 compatibility was announced with Mono, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono 2.10 has some support for memory mapped file. However it is not 100% complete (and Windows-specific things like security are not likely to be ever included) so YMMV.

You can browser what's available from the GIT repository:
https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/mono-2-10/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles

Since this is a .NET 4.0 feature you'll need to use the 'dmcs' compiler to get your code to compile (and also reference System.Core.dll where the types resides).

As for MonoTouch it provides a subset of Mono (originally based on the 2.1 profile from Silverlight and extra, even some 4.0, features). Currently (for MonoTouch 4.x) this does not include any type from System.IO.MemoryMappedFile.* namespace. Future versions will offer more .NET 4.0 features (if they are available from iOS).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer contains an important hint that I would like you to confirm: MonoTouch is coming with Mono "included" - is  that correct? If I habe MT 4.0.4 installed and change my local Mono runtime from 2.6 to 2.10, MT will not be affected (device / Simulator)?

Comment: That's right. MT itself (applications on device or simulator) won't be affected by an update of your Mono runtime. That's because MT includes it's own compilers, runtime and assemblies. However MonoDevelop (or other tools) could be affected by a Mono update (see MD requirements and the Mono release notes before updating).