# Best way to read section of large file c#

Tags: c#, text, mono, filestream, streamreader

Im working in .Net 2.0 mono for Unity3d deploying to handheld devices and desktop.
I have to parse through large txt files on startup (currently using StreamReader). These may add up to 100/200MB or more even. Reading them into line arrays is fine on desktop but not on handheld devices. I need to keep a reference to certain lines to be able to retrieve chunks of the file.

Iterating through lines to find a string takes over a second on a 10MB file on an ipad and reading 1 10MB file into a line array takes 3 seconds or so.

Is it possible to save the byte a certain line starts at so I can use a FileStream and set the position accordingly or any other suggestions on how I can do this?

Perhaps answering my own question.. Should I create my own FileStream, read in bytes and parse looking for eol chars?

edit: my search code to find a string...

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath));
string line;
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line[0] != 'g')
        continue;

    if (line.Contains(searchString)) {
        debugString = (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - temp).ToString();
        Debug.Log (Time.realtimeSinceStartup);
        break;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Limiting factors of speed are _read time + processing time_. Read time from a local drive should be assumed constant. Can you do the processing in parallel? Are you in control of the file format? Indexing the file may be required.

Comment: theyre wavefront .obj files. I do some work on them in a php web service before they reach the client app so could potentially do something to them there.. what do you mean by indexing?

Comment: Indexing a file is exactly like indexing a book. Put a contents section at the top with all the interesting locations marked so that you can skip straight the bits you want. If you _have_ to read the whole file then you may be stuck waiting I'm afraid. 10MB sounds big but not too big. Do you have any console output that might make it seems slow?

Comment: i was thinking i could limit read time if im reading in from a specific byte... or does the whole file have to read first to access from a certain byte?

Comment: ive added my search code above. Ive tested this on a release build with no excessive debugging code on an ipad 2 which will out perform other devices ill have to deploy to

Comment: No, you don't have to read the whole file. You can use `FileStream.Seek()` to skip straight to a byte. Can you add a short sample file?

Comment: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F03/models/cow-nonormals.obj heres a sample file! the only differencr with that file is that its all one object. normally there are sections of those lines and each object has a line such as "g cow"

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely read [why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html). And you should be aware of [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Avoiding CPU is one part of the equation, and Boyer-Moore and other similar algorithms are key to that (avoid looking at each char, avoid touching each memory location). Another key component is optimizing the IO, but this will depend a lot on the underlying hardware. HDD systems like sequential reads (no head movement), but this point is moot on mobile systems. In your case, I would guess that optimizing the search is the key. Tokenizing lines is probably irrelevant, a much better solution is to find the line delimiters left and right of the match, since statistically lines are usually much shorter than the file and you probably do not expect a match on each line. Read the first link.

Doing memory mapped IO instead of streamed IO will also likely yield improvements, but the Mono support for mmap is sketchy (see [System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles on MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897162/system-io-memorymappedfiles-on-monotouch)). Coding your algorithms against mmap is not trivial (you need to understand memory, pointers and the like) but it is possible, even with C#.